# Reading NUnit test data from Excel - how to access testdata?

Tags: c#, excel, nunit, data-driven-tests

I'm trying to use Excel data reader introduced here http://fabiouechi.blogspot.fi/2010/07/excel-data-driven-tests-with-nunit.html to read data for my NUnit tests.

My test data has several columns - like status, running, pressure, p_prev, temperature - and over 200 rows in excel file.

I'm using the following code to read test cases.

```
        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCaseData_T3003
    {
        get
        {
            var testcases = ExcelTestCaseDataReader.New()
                .FromFileSystem(@"C:\Tests\Test data.xlsx")
                .AddSheet("T3003")
                .GetTestCases(delegate(string sheet, DataRow row, int rowNum)
                {
                    var testName = sheet + rowNum;
                    //var category = Convert.ToString(row["col1"]);
                    IDictionary testDataArgs = new Hashtable();
                    var testData = new TestCaseData(testDataArgs).SetName(testName);
                    return testData;
                }
             );

            foreach (TestCaseData testCaseData in testcases)
            {
                yield return testCaseData;
            }
        }
    }

public List<TestCaseData> GetTestCases(Func<string, DataRow, int, TestCaseData> testCaseDataCreator)
    {
        var testDataList = new List<TestCaseData>();
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = GetExcelReader(ExcelFile);
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        foreach (var sheet in Sheets)
        {
            var sheetTable = result.Tables[sheet];
            var i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in sheetTable.Rows)
            {
                testDataList.Add(testCaseDataCreator(sheet, dr, i));
                i = i + 1;
            }    
        }

        excelReader.Close();
        return testDataList;

    }
```

and the actual test, which uses data from excel, is still very raw.

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("TestCaseData_T3003")]
    public void T3003_Excel(IDictionary testData)
    {
        //do the assertions here
    }
```

The question is, how do I access the test data in my test procedure? How do I refer to the value in a column *"status"* or *"pressure"*?

Nunit finds all rows in my test data, because it runs the test for 214 times. 
But, when I debug my code and bread in T3003_Excel, the property testData.Count is zero. So is the length of the key collection of hashtable testData.Keys. (testData.Keys.Count = 0)

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just adding an empty `HashTable` to the test case data; you need to actually put something in it.  Your delegate should be something like this:

```
...
.GetTestCases(delegate(string sheet, DataRow row, int rowNum)
{
    var testDataArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns)
    {
        testDataArgs[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
    }

    var testName = sheet + rowNum;
    return new TestCaseData(testDataArgs).SetName(testName);
}
```